# The correct way to re-render react component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component BoardManager with its initial state

```
const BoardManager = () => {
  const [boards] = useState([
    {
      name: "Board 1",
      link: "dkhgsdfj",
    },
    {
      name: "Board 2",
      link: "dkhgsdfj",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      {boards.map((val, i) => (
        <Board boardName={val.name} />
      ))}
      <AddBoardButton boards={boards} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And I have component AddBoardButton

```
function AddBoardButton({ boards }) {
  return (
    <div className="AddBoardButton">
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          boards.push({ name: "added board", link: "to be done" });
        }}
      >
        Add board
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**The behaviour I want:** I push the button and it adds new board

**Questions:**

1. `boards.push` indeed change the state of BoardManager, but how should I make React to re-render the changes in BoardManager's state in correct way?
2. And also, is changing the state of component A from component B is ok practice or should I avoid that?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Changing parent state from a child should be handled with a callback function passed to the child. In the parent the state should not be mutated directly; there are many tutorials/SO questions/etc that discuss why and how.

Comment: In addition to the answers to your question, you should also consider passing a `key` prop to your `<Board>` components. It will help React render that array more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> boards.push indeed change the state of BoardManager, but how should I
> make React to re-render the changes in BoardManager's state in correct
> way?

You are mutating the state directly which is why your component isn't re-rendering. You need to update the state correctly to trigger a re-render on state update.

To update the state correctly, you need to create a new array and merge the old state with the new one. You also need to pass state setter function, returned by `useState()` hook, as a prop to the `AddBoardButton` component.

**Board component:**

```
// destructure state setter function
const [boards, setBoards] = useState([...]);

// pass the state setter function as a prop
<AddBoardButton boards={boards} setBoards={setBoards} />
```

**AddBoardButton component:**

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const newObject = { name: "added board", link: "to be done" };
  const updatedState = [...boards newObject];

  setBoards(updatedState); 
}

// set the onClick event handler on the button
<button type="button" onClick={handleClick} />
```

> And also, is changing the state of component A from component B is ok
> practice or should I avoid that?

Child components can update the state that exists in the parent component.

There are two ways you can handle this:

- pass the state setter function as a prop to the child component
- create a callback function in the parent component and pass that callback function as a prop to the child component. This callback function should be responsible for updating the state.